create a variable using a value of another variable and store value into the newly created variable in shell/bash script
I am trying to create a Variable from value of another variable and trying to store value into the created variable in Shell Script. For Example:
Let there is a existing variable i=1
I am trying to store value in var_$i
I have tried:
i=1
"var_$i"='true'
echo "$var_1"

Output:
bash: var_1=true: command not found`

AND
i=1
var_indirect="var_$i"
${!var_indirect}='true'
echo "$var_1"

Output:
bash: =true: command not found

I am expecting that
echo $var_1 will give the output true.

The declare builtin might help, I can't find the link now but try:  declare i=1 var_$i='true'; echo "$var_1"

See https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation

Associative arrays are the way to go instead of trying to make a new variable name at runtime.

If $i is always numeric, you don't even need an an associative array, just a plain numeric-indexed one. i=1; var[i]='true'; echo "${var[1]}". In any case, dynamic variable names are a mess, and should be avoided if at all possible (usually by using some sort of array instead).

We are going to use eval. For the least amount of risk, we prepare the value to be stored into the computed variable in a variable called val
The idiom is:
eval var_$i=\$val

The argument to eval undergoes substitution, producing the syntax var_1=$val. The dollar sign is escaped, and so the escape is removed and the dollar sign is preserved.
This var_1=$val syntax is evaluated by eval, resulting in the desired assignment.
Note that A=$B assignments do not require quoting.
If a malicious user gains control over the $i variable, they can fool our eval into doing bad things. For instance, suppose i contains this text:
foo=bar; rm -rf ~/*; bar

then eval will be invoked with the argument:
var_foo=bar; rm -rf ~/*; bar=$val

a syntactically correct command sequence consisting of two assignments sandwiching a recursive removal. So you have to be very careful about how i acquires its value.
Bash has indirect variables and namerefs (by imitation of similar features found in the Korn shell).
Quick demo: indirect vars:
$ var=TERM
$ echo ${!var}
screen-256color

namerefs:
$ declare -n var=TERM
$ echo $var
screen-256color
$ var=ansi
$ echo $var
ansi
$ echo $TERM
ansi

Using a nameref we can create an alias for var_$i and set it that way:
$ i=42
$ declare -n ref=var_$i
$ ref=content
$ echo $var_42
content

This is safer than using eval, and probably more performant; just not portable. The eval method uses only POSIX shell features.

In your code:
i=1
"var_$i"='true'
echo "$var_1"


"var_$i"='true' is checked for "starts with valid variable name followed by equal character" before expansion of $i or removal of quotes is attempted, but "var_$i" is not a valid variable name so no assignment is performed

As the comments note, using declare can fix this.
i=1
declare "var_$i"=true
echo "$var_1"


Your second attempt fails for similar reason.
i=1
var_indirect="var_$i"
${!var_indirect}='true'
echo "$var_1"


${!var_indirect} is not a valid variable name, so this is not treated as assignment
also ${!var_indirect} gives a value, not a variable name

Similar fix is possible:
i=1
var_indirect=var_$i
declare "$var_indirect"=true
echo "$var_1" "${!var_indirect}"


From bash man-page:
Simple Commands
    A  simple  command  is a sequence of optional variable assignments fol‐
    lowed by blank-separated words and redirections, and  terminated  by  a
    control operator.  The first word specifies the command to be executed,
    and is passed as argument zero.  The remaining words are passed as  ar‐
    guments to the invoked command.


i=1 j=2 echo blah is 2 variable assignments followed by 2 words
i=1 "k"=v echo blah is 1 assignment followed by 3 words
declare "$k"="$v" is 2 words

Using set -k changes this behaviour.

The question had formatting issues which are now fixed; the commands weren't all on one line.

@tripleee oops, I should have checked that
